# PHP - Method to set multiple dimensions of keys for a value Session

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I made a Session class for my project. I have a `static method` **set** which set the session and I need to set multiple dimensions of keys for a value.

For example if `$keys = ['user','id]` it should be `$_SESSION['user']['id] = $value`. This is my method:

```
public static function set($keys, $value) {
    self::start();
    if(is_array($keys)) {
          // make $_SESSION[key1][key2]...[keyn] = $value
    }
}
```

Is there any possibility to make a session like in the comment? I don't know how to append the keys and add them to the $_SESSION variable.

Thanks

Comment: Just remove `make` and the `...` and that'll work fine? That is how you define keys and set them to a value.

Comment: @GeorgeAppleton but how do I get the keys there? how do I append the keys to the session in that way?

Comment: I don't know if i am getting this right, if so, i think you can use this statement to set new sessions: `$_SESSION[$key] = $value;` 
if i am not, please comment what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I see what you mean now, you should edit the question to make it clear that the issue is using an array of keys to recursively set multiple dimensions of keys for a value. Currently it reads like you're having an issue with sessions not the array, this is why minimal examples are a thing.

Comment: @yak0d3 It is better now?

Comment: @ValentinEmilCudelcu about what?

Comment: @yak0d3 I edited my post.

Comment: @ValentinEmilCudelcu Sorry i got confused, yeah it seems better now, thank you.
I'm trying to figure out a solution for this problem

Comment: I think you are not explaining your idea very well, but can you please tell me if you are trying to do something like this?
`$_SESSION['object'] = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');`
Or maybe event like this? with 18 is the index of a specific object.
`$_SESSION['object']['specific_objects'][18] = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');`

Comment: @yak0d3 `$_SESSION['object'] = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');` this is what I made first. But I wanted to be able to make `$_SESSION['user]['id']`, `$_SESSION['user']['username`]. The first option is good too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182603/discussion-between-yak0d3-and-valentin-emil-cudelcu).

Comment: The edit is a lot better than the original,  it was a good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static function set($keys, $value) {
    self::start();
    if(is_array($keys)) {
       $session = &$_SESSION;
       foreach ($keys as $key) {
          $session = $session[$key];
       }
       $session = $value;
    }
}
```

This should work, tell me if there is an issue with it

Comment: Works great. So I have to use the reference of the `$_SESSION` and append the reference of `$_SESSION[$key]`? Or maybe you could explain me a little the code.

Comment: I've got a feeling that the second & was uneeded or causes problems. But I'm on mobile so I can't check.

Comment: Yes, it works without the second `&` too.  Both cases worked (didn't get any error yet) :))

Comment: It works because by using `&` on the value I'm assigning I'm passing the value by reference. By that I mean $session doesn't actually store any data, when you say to use $session it actually uses `$_SESSION`. So now I have a variable which when assigned values will behave like I assigned them to `$_SESSION` but without any of `$_SESSION`'s restrictions. I then just go though loops, each loop changes the value of `$session` to a value inside itself defined by `$key`

Comment: Thanks. I understand now.